# Mac Outlook 2016 unread message formatting

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I just upgraded to Outlook 2016.
Previously, unread e-mails were displayed in a **bold** font.

Now, it seems it is replaced with a small vertical bar on the left. I really want the unread messages to 'pop' out like before.

I read some outlook tips on the web and I found some ways of changing the view using "View", "View Settings".

But I don't see that option in Mac.

Comment: [you are not alone](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273494-outlook-and-calendar/suggestions/12858297-unread-messages-should-be-bold-black-not-blue-i-a)